# how to write name and registration no on template and send to it's mail id

Tags: python, email, templates, sendmail, dynamically-generated

i have student database:

[image]

and i have certificate template and i want to take data from database like student name and student roll no print on template and send this template to related email id 
but i have some conditions i have two templates one for 3rd sem and other is 5th sem

using certificate template take student name roll no from student database and if student is 3rd sem send template 1st and if 5th sem send 2nd template according to its name and roll no and email id

Comment: And... what have you tried so far?

Comment: take `student name` `roll no` `semester` from database and do a validation for `semester` .. if student semester value is `3`, then post that data to one template and if semester value is `5` then post that data to another template...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have already taken data from the database into  a list or something.for every student take his name, reg no, and email.
make a sample.txt with all the email contents you want to send to student but instead of writing name use

```
${name}
```

and for reg no use

```
${regno}
```

now before sending the email get the template from text file using

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as template_file:
    template_file_content = template_file.read()
message = template_file_content.substitute(name=name_from_db.title(),regno = reg_no_from_db.title())
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

and here server is smtp server which can be coded as

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
server.starttls()
server.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASS)
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: happy to help you